# How to remove @charset in the CSS file when running npm?

Tags: laravel, npm, sass, amp-html, laravel-mix

I'm using Laravel 5.7 and i'm applying AMP to our website. (https://amp.dev/).

I'm folowing these steps to convert HTML to AMP: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/converting/?format=websites

One of the requirements is to replace external stylesheets to internal stylesheets (https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/converting/resolving-errors?format=websites#replace-external-stylesheets). I've done this by doing the following code below:

```
<style amp-custom>
    {!! file_get_contents(public_path('css/app.css')) !!}
</style>
```

I'm using Sass and I'm using Laravel mix to compile my assets.

This is my `webpack.mix.js`

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sourceMaps()
   .version();
```

But upon doing this I've encountered an error in the AMP:

```
CSS syntax error in tag 'style amp-custom' - saw invalid at rule '@charset'.
```

To solve this problem, I must remove the `@charset "UTF-8";` in the compiled css `css/app.css`. And it seems that running `npm run dev`, its automatically adding `@charset "UTF-8";` at the top of the file. How do I remove this?

I'm thinking that I have to add some code in the `webpack.mix.js` to remove that. But I don't have an idea how to do this.

Comment: From my experience, it could be something else wrong. Can you upload your Sass somewhere or paste it here if it's not too long.

Comment: You may have another problem. According to the documentation, the `!important` is not allowed in CSS. If you use bootstrap this is an issue. https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/style_pages?format=websites Before you dig in deep, you may have a look at the open-source and free https://quasar.dev

Comment: You will encounter other problems with your approach, but your comments discourage advice.

Comment: @JayGray, Can you name one SPECIFIC kind of problem that I will encounter? Don't get me wrong, I am pleased that people are trying to help me. So far, I'm doing good in converting my page to AMP pages. I am not using Bootstrap. And I have only 1 problem that is removing `@charset "UTF-8"'` in my compiled CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Yep! SASS adds this directive if your SASS contains any extended (e.g., not standard ASCII) characters. There's an open issue in the SASS project to provide an option to *not* do this... but they've said they won't provide that option.

For now, it's pretty easy to fix... simply add a step that your build process that hunts for `@charset "UTF-8";` and removes it. You can see how I did it here:

https://github.com/ampproject/samples/blob/master/amp-camp/gulpfile.js#L63

```
gulp.task('styles', function buildStyles() {
    const cssEncodingDirective = '@charset "UTF-8";';

    return gulp.src(paths.css.src)
... (stuff removed)
        .pipe(options.env === 'dev' ? replace(cssEncodingDirective, '') : noop())
... (more stuff removed)
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but I'm using Laravel mix. Is there anyway that I can do this but with `laravel-mix`

Comment: I edited my answer and added my `webpack.mix.js` code. It's pretty simple

Answer (score 0):

If you run **'npm run production'**, that line will be deleted automatically and you will not get an error in AMP validation.